# get remote image dimensions before accepting it as an upload? getimagesize() too slow

Tags: php

I've been using getimagesize() to get the dimensions of an image a user is uploading, then checking if there is enough memory to process this image. The problem is getimagesize() downloads the file to the server before reading dimensions. So its catch 22. this must be a very common problem but i havent come across a universal solution. Is there a solid way to get a remote images dimensions without downloading it?

Comment: I have the same problem. As far as I can tell, if you need the dimensions, `getimagesize()` is it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Send a `HEAD` HTTP request for the image. This will get you the response headers, but the actual body (the image) won't be sent.

Then, read those headers and look for `Content-Length`. This is a number that shows the size of the image in bytes. Using that you can determine if there's enough memory to process the image, in which case you can repeat the request as `GET` (which is what `getimagesize()` basically does)

Comment: Will this get the image dimensions too?

Comment: @Kolink can i get the image dimensions from that method too?

Comment: Does this method have any advantage over just setting `upload_max_filesize` in an `.htaccess` file?

Comment: This will not give you the image dimensions in pixels. However, it is a good first step to avoid downloading 12MB jpegs to your server. Once you have the (small enough) file on your server, its dimensions could still be too big to process, but there's no way of knowing it before.